# azure template not allowing jobs keyword

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

bare with me as this is my 2nd week really diving into pipelines on Azure but.. I saw an example where I can create a template that has a `jobs:` section..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#job-stage-and-step-templates-with-parameters

so I can properly segment things in the template.. however when I goto do this it's complaining

**yaml snippet**

```
# File: template_process_folder.yaml

parameters: 
- name: folder_name
  default: YOURFOLDER

jobs:
- job: ProcessFolder
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  displayName: "Processing Folder"
  steps:
    - bash: |
        blah blah blah
```

**Error**

```
error line X, Col 1... Unexpected value 'jobs'
```

Anyone have a idea where what I am doing wrong?  I've tried stages with it.. just 1 job.. etc.. only thing that works for me is simple steps only in templates

Edit: Could it be how I am calling my template?  Is there a way to still loop through these array values but at the job level? I have not seen that in any doc as of now

**how I call the template**

```
- stage: Build
  displayName: "Build"
  jobs:
    - job: "Execute_Tests"
      displayName: "Run Tests"
      steps:
        - ${{each p in parameters.mylistoffolders}}:
            - template: template_process_folder.yaml
              parameters:
                folder_name: ${{p}}
```

I think this is the problem.. and now am removing the template call from the `steps` area and bumping it up to the `jobs` area successfully.. but now my error is complaining that job names must be unique.. I figured just pass the folder name but it contains `-` which are not allowed.. now trying to execute a replace call but unsuccessfully

**new template job entry**

```
jobs:
- job: ProcessFolder_${{ replace(${{parameters.folder_name}}, '-', '_') }}
```

**error I get**

```
unclosed function: 'replace'. Located at position 1 within expression replace(${{paramet....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing in my side and I can see the same error `Unclosed function: 'replace'. Located at position 1 within expression: replace(${{parameters.folder_name.` It seems that this expression doesn't work here.

As a workaround, you could use keyword `displayname` so it can resolve error that job names must be unique by using `displayName: ProcessFolder_${{parameters.folder_name}}`.

BTW, the following yaml is for your reference.

**template_process_folder.yml**

```
# File: template_process_folder.yml

parameters: 
- name: folder_name
  type: string
  default: YOURFOLDER

jobs:
- job: 
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  displayName: ProcessFolder_${{parameters.folder_name}}
  steps:
    - bash: |
        echo ${{ parameters.folder_name }}
```

**template_stage.yml**

```
# File: template_stage.yml

parameters:
- name: mylistoffolders  # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  type: object
  default:
  - one
  - two

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: "Build"
  jobs:
  - ${{each p in parameters.mylistoffolders}}:
    - template: template_process_folder.yml
      parameters:
        folder_name: ${{p}}
```

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- template: template_stage.yml
  parameters:
    mylistoffolders:
    - test1-hi
    - test2-bye
```

Comment: Hi Erik, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Answer (score 1):

By "moving the template call from the steps area up to the jobs area", you have almost solved the issue yourself. To avoid the issue of unique job name, you just need to remove the name that you assigned to the job. If you need it to display a name, use the suggestion from "Edward Han-MSFT" with displayName attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the YAML pipeline syntax is not as straightforward as the Classic Editor experience. :)

But the best way to get started here is to first understand the structure of a pipeline, to know what are the must-have components vs what can be skipped.

As explained in the [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema) document, the hierarchy looks like this:

[image: Pipeline Structure]

Note that your YAML definition may not need to include all of them as simple pipelines don't require all of these levels.

You can quickly experiment building a new pipeline with the available [quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline) to see this in action, and then advance to learning how to configure your YAML pipeline for your specific use-case.

The schema reference article linked above contains an example for every pipeline component accompanied by an example yaml snippet that should help make the usage clearer.

P.S.: Indentation is the one of the most important aspects to be wary of when working with YAML definitions!